# How to Compare Two Values Between Two Sheets And Sum Them Based On a Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, they have almost the same data, but not 100% equal.

I need to get the CPF(col A) from my client on the sheet1 and check if exists on sheet2(col A), if exists I need to check if CEP(col k) from this client is equal to CEP(col C) on the sheet2.

I need only sum the cases where the client on the sheet1 has on the col L the text "success".

**Sheet1**

```
A - CPF | ... | K - CEP | L - STATUS |
   123  | ... |  1234-5 |  Success   | <- Has changed CEP
   124  | ... |  1200-0 |  Success   | <- CEP not changed.
   987  | ... |  0503-7 |  Failed    |
```

---

**Sheet2**

```
A - CPF | ... | C - CEP |
   123  | ... |  1234-0 | <- Original CEP
   124  | ... |  1200-0 | <- Original CEP
   987  | ... |  0503-7 |
```

---

**Expected**

SUM: 1.

This sum goes into another sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula (anywhere):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!L:L="success")*(Sheet1!K:K=Sheet2!C:C))
```

It can be calculated faster if you set limited column ranges instead of full columns. For example if you know that the number of rows will not exceed 10000,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!L2:L9999="success")*(Sheet1!K2:K9999=Sheet2!C2:C9999))
```

---

- Some explanation

The formula aligns two boolean vectors.

The first has 1's where `Sheet1!L:L="success"`, zeros elsewhere.

The second has one's where `Sheet1!K:K=Sheet2!C:C`, zeros elsewhere.

Then we multiply these two vectors to enforce a logical `AND` of the two criteria.

Finally `SUMPRODUCT` counts the number of ones, thus the number of rows that match all the criteria.